# How can I fill the image in CurvedNavigationBar icon?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, icons

I am using [curved_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar). I used Image.asset to the icon of `CurvedNavigationbar`. There remains few gap in icon. Now how to fill the image in the CurvedNavigationBar icon.

This is the code I am using:

```
bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0x00ffffff),
          color: navigationBarColor,
          animationCurve: Curves.easeIn,
          index: _currentIndex,
          items: [
            Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: navitionBarIconColor),
            Icon(Icons.notifications, color: navitionBarIconColor),
            _currentIndex != 2
                ? Icon(Icons.home, color: navitionBarIconColor)
                : ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(HomeIconSize / 2),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'images/moharajIcon/logo1.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      width: HomeIconSize,
                      height: HomeIconSize,
                      // color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
            Icon(Icons.list_alt, color: navitionBarIconColor),
            Icon(Icons.person, color: navitionBarIconColor),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
            });
          },
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the styling properties for it, Please share some code for the design

Comment: @SagarAcharya I have shared my code. which styling property you are talking about? can you be more specific?

Comment: Which Gap you are talking about, Is it the one around the image in blue which is border or something else

Comment: Try changing the BoxFit to BoxFit.cover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This padding is hard-coded on [`CurvedNavigationBar`](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar)'s [source code, line 123](https://github.com/rafalbednarczuk/curved_navigation_bar/blob/890451aea70e34b81d2a302018da1ad9ee6fd6e3/lib/curved_navigation_bar.dart#L123):

[image]

You can set padding 0 or remove the padding widget [on source-code](https://github.com/rafalbednarczuk/curved_navigation_bar/blob/890451aea70e34b81d2a302018da1ad9ee6fd6e3/lib/curved_navigation_bar.dart#L123).

Else, you can do a trick using `buttonBackgroundColor:`

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
  buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
```